# how i can post response of google reCAPTCHA with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I want to check reCaptcha answer from Google in asp.net.  If the client did not select "i am not robot" the form will not submit.  I wrote codes below in C# but it doesn't work as expected.  Anybody can help me?

```
public class ReCaptchaClass{
public static string Validate(string EncodedResponse)
{
    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();


    string PrivateKey = "--secret-key--";

    var GoogleReply = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", PrivateKey, EncodedResponse));

    var captchaResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReCaptchaClass>(GoogleReply);

    return captchaResponse.Success.ToLower();
}

[JsonProperty("success")]
public string Success
{
    get { return m_Success; }
    set { m_Success = value; }
}

private string m_Success;
[JsonProperty("error-codes")]
public List<string> ErrorCodes
{
    get { return m_ErrorCodes; }
    set { m_ErrorCodes = value; }
}
private List<string> m_ErrorCodes;
}
```

And I used the string below for checked in :

```
string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptchaClass.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "true" ? true : false);

if (IsCaptchaValid)
{
    //Valid Request
}
```

Comment: `but it doesn't work as expected` What was your expectation? What did it actually do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I use in my WEB API Controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage(string encodedResponse)
    {
        var url = $"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=--secret-key--&response={encodedResponse}";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, null))
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                if (!(bool)json["success"])
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }
            }
        }

        // CODE HERE WHEN THE REQUEST IS OK


        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Don't using HttpClient in a using statement. It's supposed to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application.